# Device driver in virtual memory system

Tags: driver, device, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory, memory-mapping

Assume that there is a device using memory-mapped I/O i.e. there is a specific range of physical memory assigned to this device

If virtual memory system is not used, then it is quite straightforward to manipulate the device through read/write operations done with corresponding physical addresses

What if there is virtual memory system ?

Device driver needs to be aware of that specific range of physical memory assigned to that device, but how does it access that address range if it should use virtual addresses instead of physical ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of memory mapped IO devices, any physical address shared by that device can be mapped to the kernel virtual memory using the ioremap() API [1].

Hence in your case, we can map the physical address 0x1234 using ioremap() to obtain its kernel virtual address and start writing data to this address.

[1] http://lxr.gwbnsh.net.cn/linux/arch/cris/mm/ioremap.c

Comment: is that actually a way how it is done when memory-mapped I/O device drivers are written?

Comment: Yes, it is. Take a look at this serial driver written for TI OMAP chipset, you can see how the UART physical address range is remapped to VM. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c#L1496

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've done it, but my recollection is that when you map a block of physical memory, the address in your user space corresponds to that physical memory.  Writing to your user-space address is a write to the physical memory.

Comment: i don't think that i quite understand what you mean. what i'm saying is that for example, my program wants to send a char via serial port and hence calls some serial_sendchar() routine which is a part of serial device driver. assume that in order to send a char via serial port we have to write this char into PHYSICAL address 0x1234. My question is how does serial_sendchar() routine write into that particular address if it is supposed to use virtual addresses ? if it has to write to that specific physical address then it should bypass virtual-to-physical translation, shouldn't it?